# Scala & Spark: Add value to every cell of every row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a two `DataFrame`s:

```
scala> df1.show()
+----+----+----+---+----+
|col1|col2|col3|   |colN|
+----+----+----+   +----+
|   2|null|   3|...|   4|
|   4|   3|   3|   |   1|
|   5|   2|   8|   |   1|
+----+----+----+---+----+

scala> df2.show() // has one row only (avg())
+----+----+----+---+----+
|col1|col2|col3|   |colN|
+----+----+----+   +----+
| 3.6|null| 4.6|...|   2|
+----+----+----+---+----+
```

and a constant `val c : Double = 0.1`.

Desired output is a `df3: Dataframe` that is given by

[image: entries of df3],

with *n=numberOfRow* and *m=numberOfColumn*.

I already looked through the list of [`sql.function`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)s and failed implementing it myself with some nested `map` operations (fearing performance issues). One idea I had was:

```
val cBc = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(c)
val df2Bc = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(averageObservation)
df1.rdd.map(row => {
   for (colIdx <- 0 until row.length) {
      val correspondingDf2value = df2Bc.value.head().getDouble(colIdx)

      row.getDouble(colIdx) * (1 - cBc.value) + correspondingDf2value * cBc.value
   }
})
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you the code you have tried?

Comment: thanks ! I addded the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(cross)join` combined with `select` is more than enough and will be much more efficient than mapping. Required imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{broadcast, col, lit}
```

and expression:

```
val exprs = df1.columns.map { x => (df1(x) * (1 - c) +  df2(x) * c).alias(x) }
```

`join` and `select`:

```
df1.crossJoin(broadcast(df2)).select(exprs: _*)
```

Comment: Awesome ! Fantastic conept (generating simple select expressions, aliasing to original columns, broadcasting the smaller DataFrame and a simple select). Thanks, like magic. Thanks for bringing `crossJoin` up